# How to link to users show page in the view

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I added a link to the Photos page so that below each picture it would link to the users page.

The issue is I am getting redirected to `/photos/1` when I should be directed to `/users/1`

Photos controller:

```
  def show
    @photos = Photo.find(username: params[:id])    
  end
```

View:

```
<% @photos.each do |photo| %>
    <%= link_to photo.user, photo %>

       <%=image_tag photo.image_url(:thumb) %>
    <%= button_to "remove", photo, :confirm => 'Are you sure?', :method => :delete %>
    <% end %>
```

Comment: Your code is a little bit confusing. Why are you using find instead of where in the controller? Then you pass the photo object as argument for the link_to, it will clearly redirect to the photo, not the user. Are you using the user object as the text for your link? Anyway, I think the link should look something like <%= link_to photo.user.username, photo.user %>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As noted, using `<%= link_to photo.user.username, photo.user %>` should give you what you're looking for.